# Populate ListView with images from SQLite in Android

Tags: android

I'm an Android Application Developer. I'm new to it. I am currently developing an application which requires me to insert and retrieve set of images stored in an SQLite database to display into ListView. Can anyone please help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is recommended to store images in an SQL database, especially if the image sizes are more than 1MB.

I would store a list of the image names in the SQLite database, and then add these programatically to the list view.

Comment: No. Image sizes are around 5kb.

Comment: I would still recommend storing the images in the filesystem (not SQLite), when a user installs a new application the SQL databases will be empty. This means that you will have to send the images to the user via internet connection which will take considerable bandwidth.

Comment: Okay! Then, how to retrieve with image names.?

Comment: First you would need to create the SQLite database schema, then put information into the database, following this would be retrieval. A full guide is written here:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Okay! Thanks. But, can you give me an example? Like, retrieving 3 to 4 images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14934449/2662639